# Trying to attach JQuery on another page attached through data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have  a slider which attaches slides through external page attached through data attributes.

Here is what's happening:-

### Main Page

```
<div id="sitewrapper">
    <section class="sliderwrapper">
        <div id="slider" data-source="slides-page.html" data-speed="500" data-easing="swing">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="loader"><span id="load"></span></div>
        <a class="button" id="back"></a>
        <a class="button" id="next"></a>
    </section>
<!--end sitewrapper-->
</div>

<script>
    $(function() { //run when the DOM is ready
   $('.internalclick').click(function(e) {
       alert("I clicked Area Tag" + $(this).attr('data-direct'));
      });

    });
</script>
```

### Slides page (slides-page.html)

```
    <li class="hslide" data-id="1"><img src="content/01.png" usemap="#Map">
      <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="331,158,538,297" href="#" class="internalclick" data-direct="I-need-to-direct">
        <area shape="rect" coords="546,154,745,305" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="331,311,543,445" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="550,309,733,443" href="#">
      </map>
    </li>
    <li class="hslide" data-id="2"><img src="content/02.png"></li>
    <li class="hslide" data-id="3"><img src="content/03.png"></li>
    <li class="hslide" data-id="4"><img src="content/04.png"></li>
```

### Problem

Now above all works fine when I try to add a Click function on two the list elements (slides) in the slides page. Notice the first  where I added `href="#" class="internalclick" data-direct="I-need-to-direct"`. Now the problem is to access it.

When I am trying to run a small Click function in the main page, I am unable to run the function. Any idea how I can make a click function that scopes the area tag in the slides page?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using `.data()`?

Comment: The problem is either the slide code uses an iframe or you are attaching the click before the slideshow loads the content.  `$("#sitewrapper").on("click",".internalclick", function(e) { console.log( $(this).data("direct")); });`

Comment: Thank you very much epascarello. May be you can write it as an Answer for me to accept it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `internalclick` is loaded after you add the event handlers. You need to use event delegation.

```
$("#sitewrapper").on("click",".internalclick", function(e) { 
    var direct = $(this).data("direct");
    console.log(direct);
});
```